# populate google extension with data from local database

Tags: javascript, sql, database, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

======================manifest.json==========================

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "URL pins",
  "description": "",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "http://localhost/pinterest/extension.php"
  ]
}
```

====================popup.js======================

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function checkusername(){
    var status = document.getElementById("plugin");
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    hr.open("GET", "http://localhost/pinterest/extension.php", true);
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
            status.innerHTML = hr.responseText;
        }
    }
    hr.send();
}
}
</script>
```

=======================popup.html==========================

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Getting Started Extension's Popup</title>
    <style>
      body {
        min-width: 357px;
        overflow-x: hidden;
      }

      img {
        margin: 5px;
        border: 2px solid black;
        vertical-align: middle;
        width: 75px;
        height: 75px;
      }
    </style>

    <!--
      - JavaScript and HTML must be in separate files: see our Content Security
      - Policy documentation[1] for details and explanation.
      -
      - [1]: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html
     -->
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="plugin"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

=============entension.php========================

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'database.php';
    $uid=$_SESSION['user']['id'];
    $string = '<input type="text" name="url" id="url" placeholder="URL...."><br>';
    $result = mysql_query("select * from board where userid='$uid'",$con);
    $string .="<select name='board'>";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                unset($id, $name);
                  $id = $row['boardid'];
                  $name = $row['boardname']; 
                  $string .= '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$name.'</option>';

    }
    $string .= "</select></br>";
    echo $string;
    exit();

?>
```

I am trying to fetch all the boards which user have created in the database and pop it on chrome extension.
When i click on extension I see empty popup but when i run extension.php in browser it showa expected output.
I am new to google extensions can any1 please help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not binding the `checkusername()` function to any event, thus it is never executed.
To fix this, add the following lines to your `popup.js`:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    checkusername();
});
```

BTW, to debug such issues:

- Right click on the browser-action button and choose "Inspect popup".
- In the Developer Tools panel that opens go to the `Network` tab.
- Inspect any requests made from your popup-related code (the request-/response-headers, the response body etc).

<sub>(While the Developer Tools panel stays open, so does your popup, so you can interact with other windows/panels while debugging.)</sub>

---

<sub>BTW, you have one extra `}` in your `popup.js` (which doesn't help either).</sub>